# JFreeChart disable zooming

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there an easy way to disable zoom in/out feature for XYPlot which is drawn in ChartComposite ? Overriding the zoom methods for XYPlot will be a solution but I wonder if there is an easy way..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
getYourChartPanel().setDomainZoomable(false);
getYourChartPanel().setRangeZoomable(false);
```

See [setDomainZoomable()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setDomainZoomable(boolean)) and [setRangeZoomable()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setRangeZoomable(boolean))

Comment: I'm not using ChartPanel, I'm using ChartComposite for SWT. ChartConposite does not have setDomainZoomable() and setRangeZoomable() methods..

Comment: That would have been helpful to note in original question.

Comment: I found that ChartComposite has setDomainZoomable() and setRangeZoomable() methods too..